# Any build-in JSON.parse in MongoDB?

Tags: json, parsing, mongodb

Is there any Mongo (command line) function that I can turn a string into object? e.g. JSON.parse or something like that?

db.sessions.update({}, {'$set':{ 'extra':JSON.parse(stringData)   }});

---

my solution:

```
function my_extra() {
  db.tempData.find().forEach( function(obj) {
                       obj.extra = db.eval(obj.myString);
                       db.tempData.save(obj);
                     } );
};

my_extra();
```

However, I try this: db.tempData.update({}, {'$set':{ 'extra':db.eval(myString)   }});
but it doesn't work.. saying myString is not defined.
so i use this.myString but doesn't work neither.  that's why I have to use the function.

is there a way to reference myString in the second parameter?

Comment: What is it exactly that you're trying to do? If you want to import a bunch of data there is a command-line import tool http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Import+Export+Tools

Comment: What I want to do is.. the current data I have contains stringified JSON object.  e.g. stringData:"{\"key\":12345}"

I want to parse it and assign back to the record under a new variable.  :)

Comment: I know I can use node.js or others to extract the data, json parse, and save it back.  but I have close to 1M records.  I think doing it in mongo will be faster.

Answer (score 9):

The version 2.1+ Mongo shell includes a `JSON` utility object:

- From object to JSON: `JSON.serialize(object)`
- From JSON to object: `JSON.parse(string)`

http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.6/com/mongodb/util/JSON.html

Note: In version 2.4+ Mongo shell, use `JSON.stringify()` instead of `JSON.serialize()`
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.4-javascript/

Answer (score 5):

You can try `eval` function:

```
obj = eval("(function() { return {\"key\": \"value\"} })()")
```

But note it's unsafe because it can execute arbitrary Javascript code including `db.dropDatabase()`.

Comment: thanks. that's not a worry for me coz the data is generated internally. :D  thanks.

Comment: Thanks.. Here it is:

function my_extra() {
  db.tempData.find().forEach( function(obj) {
                       obj.extra = db.eval(obj.string);
                       db.tempData.save(obj);
                     } );
}

my_extra();

Comment: @murvinlai `db.eval` is not really the same as `eval`, it executes DB command `$eval` (means roundtrip to the server) while `eval` is executed inside shell. Glad it helped anyway, feel free to mark the answer ;)