# How to parse JSON in Mongo script

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb

As part of a MongoDB script, I need to parse JSON. (Not something you would typically do, but it is Javascript after all).

`JSON.parse` does not exist.

Here is the workaround I made:

```
function parseJSON(json) {
    return eval("(function() { return "+json+"; })()");
}
```

This doesn't seem like it would be performant, and it looks a little ridiculous. Does anyone have a better way?

Comment: The function call isn't needed `return eval("("+json+")");`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Any build-in JSON.parse in MongoDB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7666324/any-build-in-json-parse-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 0):

If you really have to convert a JSON string into a JavaScript object, then what you suggest is perfectly reasonable, although there are reasons to avoid eval due to performance concerns and security risks (see [When is JavaScript's eval() not evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197769/when-is-javascripts-eval-not-evil)). In the case that you generated the JSON data and you are sure that there's nothing dangerous inside, then you probably don't have to worry about an injection vulnerability.

As far as performance, I'm not aware of anything better other than JSON.parse. Can you alter the design of your program so that you do not have to parse JSON? For example, for importing JSON data into MongoDB, instead of using eval you should use the [mongoimport](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/) utility.

Comment: JSON.parse is not available in Mongo (but if it were, I would want to use it).