# MongoDB, convert string to list

Tags: javascript, regex, mongodb, mongodb-query

we have a MongoDB to store order information, right now, the "item_list" is a string like

```
"item_list" : "[{\"item_id\":14243,\"price\":7500,\"quantity\":1},{\"item_id\":1424,\"price\":2500,\"quantity\":1}]"
```

which is a string, how do I convert it to a list object?

I want it to end up like :

```
 "item_list" : [{item_id:14243,price:7500,quantity:1},{item_id:1424,price:2500,quantity:1]
```

Comment: How did you end up with this?:-) Do you want to do this in the shell? are you using any driver?

Comment: @user3100115, edited the question, got no special driver, just base mongo command line

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7666324/any-build-in-json-parse-in-mongodb

Comment: is `item_list` string for all documents in the collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks a real mess. This should make things right.

You need to replace your invalid JSON then `.parse()` it:

```js
 var bulk = db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp(),
     count = 0;

 db.collection.find({ "item_list": { "$type": 2 } }).forEach(function(doc) {

     doc.item_list = doc.item_list.replace(new RegExp("(\"quantity\":\\d+)","g"),"$1},");
     doc.item_list = doc.item_list.replace(new RegExp(",]$"),"]");
     doc.item_list = JSON.parse(doc.item_list);

     printjson(doc.item_list);

     bulk.find({ "_id": doc._id }).update({
         "$set": { "item_list": doc.item_list }
     });
     count++;

     if ( count % 1000 == 0 ) {
         bulk.execute();
         bulk = db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
     }

 });

 if ( count % 1000 != 0 ) {
     bulk.execute();
 }
```

Posting since everyone else has not realized the JSON is invalid.

Comment: I re-edit the problem, the json should be valid, just a type error

Answer (score 0):

Considering you data as :

```
"item_list" : "[{\"item_id\":14243,\"price\":7500,\"quantity\":1},{\"item_id\":1424,\"price\":2500,\"quantity\":1}]"
```

you can use following script to update all documents:

```
db.collection.find().forEach(function(obj) {
    //var a = eval(obj.item_list); you can use eval also
    var a = JSON.parse(doc.item_list); 

    db.collection.update({
    "_id": obj._id
    }, {
    $set: {
        "item_list": a
    }
    });
});
```

Comment: The JSON string is invalid. So it needs to be fixed.